# Can WSO2 BAM Server monitors the statistics of service registered in WSO2 governance registry?

Tags: web-services, wso2, monitoring, wso2-bam

I am looking for monitoring service statistics(like how many invokes, average time taken etc.)  using WSO2 BAM server that is registered in wso2 governance registry. Please suggest how we can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure BAM to accept events from G-Reg and then publish events from G-Reg to BAM listeners. 
Refer the following documentation and go through the samples linked in that.
http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Business+Activity+Monitor

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse. Please let me know, can I get the statistics of the service registered in wso2 greg (but deployed is other ESB server not wso2)? and how to invoke a service registered in wso2 greg?, do I get a separate URL to invoke a service if I register it in wso2 greg.